# Can I drive with just a copy of a missing license?

Tags: driving

I have an Oklahoma CDL and I lost it at a truck stop in Oklahoma.  Can I still drive with just a photocopy of my driver license?

Answer (score 6):

I would *inform* the authorities about that loss as soon as possible (consider that your lost license could be found by a criminal who then conveniently "loses" it during a bank robbery), and ask them how to get a replacement license as soon as possible.

See here: http://www.dmv.org/ok-oklahoma/replace-cdl.php

That website actually recommends having a copy of your CDL with you at all times, or your company should have a copy on their files they can fax to you, so it would seem legal to drive with a copy.

There is a difference between "driving license" in the sense "the permission given to you by the state to drive a car on public roads" and "driving license" in the sense "a piece of paper or plastic giving evidence that you have permission to drive". In most countries, driving without license is a serious offence, while driving without the piece of plastic is a minor offence.

Comment: In some countries, not informing authorities about missing document and/or not requesting replacement can be a minor offense, too. Don't know about Oklahoma.

Comment: Conversely, at least in USA, the state can "suspend" your license for a period for things like driving drunk.
It is illegal to drive while suspended even though you still have the piece of plastic -- and can still use it for identification.

Comment: I was once pulled over when I had forgotten my wallet at home, but I had memorized my license number; the officer was able to enter the number into his computer to verify the license's validity, which was sufficient.